# How do I get the value [n] in text with Python?

Tags: python, text

```
text = {

1

title(1)

context(1)

2

title(2)

context(2)



...



n

title(n)

context(n)

}
```

If you can read only the numeric string to get the last value [n] in a text file, or if you can get the maximum value [n] in the whole column, or in any other way I would appreciate any explanation. The context can be multiple lines and can contain large numbers, so please exclude the context line from the calculation.

Because I am a beginner, I would really appreciate it if you describe it by function rather than by words.

Comment: what is this Input ? can you give us the input as it is on your machine ?

Comment: What does the actual file look like? Are you looking for lines containing only a single number?

Comment: yes, im looking for lines containing only a single number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the only lines with single numbers are all that you are interested in, you can use the regular expression [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) library.

Assuming that `text` contains your full text as string

```py
import re

all_numbers = re.findall(r'(?m)^\d+$', text)
last_number = int(all_numbers[-1])
highest_number = max(int(n) for n in all_numbers)
```

A quick explanation of the regular expression `r'(?m)^\d+$'`:

- `(?m)` sets the [re.M[ULTILINE]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) flag, so that lines in `text` are treated separately
- `^` normally matches the beginning of the whole string, but with the `re.M` flag, it matches the beginning of a line
- `\d+` matches one ore more decimal numbers, equivalent to `[0-9]+`
- `$` normally matches the end of the whole string, but with the `re.M` flag, it matches the end of a line

Comment: thanks a lot. i will try it